# WHEN ELSE in Case expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am writing `case` expression in my SQL Server where I want to add hard coded value in else block.

I want to check in case expression that if the below DHB output are `2.1` and `ABC001`  then It should display hardcoded value of `ABC Hospital`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    userid, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('-', e.name) > 0 
          THEN Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(e.name,0, charIndex('-', e.name)))) 
       ELSE e.name 
    END as DHB      
FROM
    [Table1].[dbo].Event ae
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].cUser cu ON cu.name = ae.userID
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].UAttribute ua ON ua.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifier] ei ON ei.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifierType] e ON e.uniqueId = ei.externalIdentifierType
WHERE
    (e.name LIKE '%ABC001%' OR e.name LIKE '2.1')
    AND userId = 'Al5'
```

Current output

```
          userid    DHB
           Al5     2.1
           Al5      ABC001
           Bl5     3.1
           Bl5      CDE001
```

Expected output

```
          userid    DHB
           Al5     ABC Hospital
           Bl5      EFG Hospital
```

I tried something like this below

```
CASE WHEN Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(e.name,0, charIndex('-', e.name)))) = 'ABC001' THEN 'ABC Hospital'
      WHEN e.name = '2.1' THEN 'ABC Hospital'
      ELSE e.name 'ABC Hospital'
  END as DHB
```

But It does not allow me to put in `ELSE e.name 'ABC Hospital'`.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: You say you expect a hardcoded value of "ABC Hospital," the problem is that you never hard code a value of "ABC Hospital." Start there.

Comment: To get expected output remove or condition for "2.1" - `where  (e.name like '%ABC001%')`

Comment: @Fabio, I need to check both conditions in my `where` clause.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, can you please suggest me solution for this?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a single atomic value - it's **not** a statement ...

Comment: @marc_s, Thank you! Can you please help me with some solutions?

Comment: can you show some sample data from your table? Not sure if this statement actually run as there is no table aliased as "e" yet you reference columns from that table!

Comment: Hi @Harry, Can you please check now. Thanks

Comment: what about the sample data? Not the output of your curent query, but what the column actual holds.. what values are present.. so we can see if your case statement will work

Comment: just change this line  ``ELSE e.name 'ABC Hospital'`` to ``ELSE 'ABC Hospital'``

Comment: `[Table1].[dbo].Event` Do you REALLY have a database named "Table1"? And why do you use three party names (db.schema.table)? Generally speaking, your connection should determine the database to use for your table references - otherwise, your code becomes more difficult to use in different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve your issue and update the query to fulfil your need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid,
CASE WHEN DHB in ('2.1','ABC001') THEN 'ABC Hospital'
ELSE DHB END 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    userid, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('-', e.name) > 0 
          THEN Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(e.name,0, charIndex('-', e.name)))) 
       ELSE e.name 
    END as DHB      
FROM
    [Table1].[dbo].Event ae
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].cUser cu ON cu.name = ae.userID
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].UAttribute ua ON ua.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifier] ei ON ei.cUser = cu.uniqueId
JOIN
    [Portal].[dbo].[EIdentifierType] e ON e.uniqueId = ei.externalIdentifierType
WHERE
    (e.name LIKE '%ABC001%' OR e.name LIKE '2.1')
    AND userId = 'Al5'
) as aa
```